# Area under curve ggplotly R not rendering as per expectation

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly, geom-ribbon

I have created a plot with the following dataset and ggplot2

I downloaded the dataset in CSV from the below link

https://www.kaggle.com/dataset/e392d3cfbb5749653d5c82f4bec1daa03628fb06d374fad84eac319f1b3f982422

The code I have used is as follows

```
 library(readr)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(plotly)
```

Next I create the dataframe from the CSV file

```
DF <- read_csv("C:/Users/mysystem/Desktop/Random3.csv")####Please set your working directory here
```

Now I create a plot using ggplot

```
p2<-ggplot(DF, aes(x=Col1, y=Col2, group=ID)) +
 geom_line(size=.5) +  geom_ribbon(data=subset(DF, Col1>1  ),aes(x=Col1,ymax=Col2, 
fill=ID),ymin=0,alpha=0.3 ) +
scale_fill_manual(name='Legend', values=c("green4",  "red"), labels=c("A", "B" ))+labs(x="Col1", 
y="Col2")+ xlim(0, 10000)+ theme_bw()# +theme(legend.position='none')
```

The above plot shows the area under the curves properly. When i run ggplotly however, the area under curves get inverted

```
ggplotly(p2)
```

Is there a way this can be avoided. The Shaded area appears to move beyond the area under the curves in some cases and in this case seems to move to the inverse of the curve. i request someone to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just wanting `geom_area` instead of `geom_ribbon`. You can also set the first value to 0 instead of skipping it to prevent the reverse filling that the resultant polygon has.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

DF <- read.csv("Random3.csv")

DF$Col2[DF$Col1 == 0] <- 0

p2 <- ggplot(DF, aes(x = Col1, y = Col2, group = ID)) +
        geom_line(size = 0.5) +  
        geom_area(aes(x = Col1, fill = ID), alpha = 0.3, 
                  position = "identity") +
        scale_fill_manual(name = 'Legend', 
                          values = c("green4", "red"), 
                          labels = c("A", "B")) + 
        labs(x = "Col1", y = "Col2") + 
        xlim(0, 10000) + 
        theme_bw()

p2 

ggplotly(p2)
```

[image]

Comment: This helps yes. But the issue of the green shade overflowing the line persists. That happens in other versions of this chart also

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs I think you just need to add `position = "identity"` because the areas are stacked by default